# PHP & Form Refresh

Tags: php, html, forms

I am building a form and using PHP to handle the request to a mail client. Now, when the user submits the form, I don't want the page to refresh, nor do I want it to go back all the way up to the top.

I want it to submit, then post the message I have supplied which is in the same place as the form without refresh. AJAX maybe?

Here is the code

PHP

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

$name=$_POST['first_name'];
$email=$_POST['exampleInputEmail1'];
$description=$_POST['description'];
$toaddress = "info@speeakly.com";
$subject = "Propective User";

$mailcontent = "Name: ".$name."\n".
                "Customer Email: ".$email."\n".
                "Customer Description:\n".$description."\n";

$fromaddress = "From: $name";
$messageaftersending = "Thank you, ".$name."! \n".
                      " You've signed up for something awesome. \n";

mail($toaddress, $subject, $mailcontent, $fromaddress);
$hidemydiv = "hide";
}?>
```

HTML

```
<span class="thanksmessage text-faded"><?php echo $messageaftersending ?></span>
 <div class="<?php echo $hidemydiv ?>">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="formstyle">
     <form role="form" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" name="myemailform" method="post">

       <div class="col-lg-4 labels">
          <fieldset class="form-group">
             <label class="labels" for="firstname">First Name*</label>
                <input type="text" name="first_name" class="form-control styled" required pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9s\-\s]+" onkeyup="" id="firstname"  pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+">
          </fieldset>
          <span class="error"><p id="name_error"></p></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Your intuition is correct. If you want to post a form to and read a response from the server without refreshing the page or navigating away, you should look into AJAX

Comment: I will look into this. Still fairly new with all of the processing.

Answer (score 1):

Ajax is the way to go.
Create a php file that accepts the post params and returns JSON

```
<?php
/* your mail code */
if (all_good) {
   echo(json_encode(array('success' => true));
} else {
   echo(json_encode(array('success' => false));
}
?>
```

Now create an XHR object to send request to server and based on the response, show the text. Use:

```
var data = JSON.parse(response.text)
```

to parse the JSON datat sent from PHP.
I would suggest using jQuery.post() instead of XHR though.

Comment: I am not quite sure how to use JSON but I'll have a look.